# Proportion of periodic points of $x^{n}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p$ be a prime. Consider $f_{p}:\mathbb{F}_{p}\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_{p}, x\mapsto x^{n}$. 
I want to show that $\liminf_{p\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\#Per(f_{p})}{p} = 0$, where $\#Per(f_{p})$ is the number of $f_{p}$-periodic points in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.

**My attempt:**
Notice that for every $r\geqslant 0$ the Dirichlet theorem for primes in arithmetic progressions implies that there exists infinitely many primes $p$ satisfying $p\equiv 1\mod n^{r}$. Notice that since $(\mathbb{F}_{p})^{*}$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1$, and thus since $n^{r}$ divides $p-1$ there are precisely $n^{r}$ elements in $(\mathbb{F}_{p})^{*}$ whose order divides $n^{r}$. One can show that a point $z$ in $(\mathbb{F}_{p})^{*}$ is $f_{p}$-periodic if and only if the order of $z$ is  coprime to $n$. From here I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most of the way there! You are clearly aware of the statement: if $d\mid(p-1)$, then there are exactly $d$ elements of $\Bbb F_p^*$ of order dividing $d$. Apply this with $d$ equal to the largest divisor $D$ of $p-1$ that is coprime to $n$, so that "order dividing $D$" is equivalent to "order coprime to $n$". It remains only to show that $D \mid (p-1)/n^r$ (under the assumption that $n^r\mid(p-1)$), which I offer to you as a challenge.

Comment: Since $D$ divides $p-1$ there exists a $l\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $D\cdot l = p-1$. Since $D$ and $n$ are coprime we find that since $n^{r}$ divides $p-1$ that $n^{r}$ has to divide $l$.Thus $p-1 = D\cdot n^{r}\cdot k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Consequently we indeed see that $D$ divides $(p-1)/n^{r}$. Thus we have at most $D+1\leqslant 1 + (p-1)/n^{r}\leqslant 1 + (p/n^{r})$ $f_{p}$-periodic points (since $0$ is also $f_{p}$-periodic). Thus for this particular $p$ we have $\frac{\#Per(f_{p})}{p}\leqslant \frac{1}{n^{r}}+\frac{1}{p}$. I still have problems to finish the proof from here.

Comment: By using the above I can show that for every prime $p$ we have for every $r\geqslant 0$ that $\inf_{p'\geqslant p}\frac{\#Per(f_{p})}{p}\leqslant \frac{1}{n^{r}} + \frac{1}{p}$. But I have problems with concluding formally that $\liminf_{p\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\#Per(f_{p})}{p} = 0$.

Comment: One can ofcourse first take a limit of $r$ to $\infty$, and then the limit from $p$ to $\infty$.